# rails form partial for new and edit on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, partial-views, form-for

I am running into issues trying to separate a form from a view into a partial. I want to use the same form for the new and edit views. These are both on the same page. The new model form is at the top of the page and uses a variable that I set in the controller.

```
<%= form_for @new_hire do |f| %>
<%= render :partial => 'new_hire_requests/form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
<% end %>
```

I then have a partial for the pending approvals that gets rendered by another partial

```
<%= render :partial => 'pending_approval', :collection => @pending_approval %>
```

And inside the pending approval partial I have this

```
<%= form_for pending_approval do |f| %>
<%= render :partial => 'new_hire_requests/form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
<% end %>
```

This is throwing an error

```
undefined method `new_hire_request_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010488ac98>:0x0000010223ffc0>
```

Is there a way to re use the form code for both a new and edit form on the same page?

Controller Logic

```
@new_hire = NewHireRequest.new
@new_hire_requests = current_user.new_hire_requests
@pending_approval = @new_hire_requests.select{|p| p.status == 'pending_hr_approval' || p.status == 'pending_exec_approval'}
```

Partial code

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<fieldset class="first">
<%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</fieldset>
<%= f.submit "Submit for Approval <i class='icon-share-alt icon-white'></i>", 
        class: "button_green" %>
```

Comment: what is pending_approval object in your edit action and what is @new_hire in your new action ?

Comment: they are both objects instantiated from the controller

`@new_hire = NewHireRequest.new`

@pending_approval is a collection of NewHireRequest objects, so the partial is rendered for each object in the collection

Comment: are they the same objects ? can you put in your controller logic and the form partial as well ?

Comment: The code looks fine then. can you share the content of new_hire_requests/form ?

Comment: so i tried moving the form out of the form partial and into the pending_approval partial and am still seeing the same error. i am guessing this has to do with the collection render and the way the objects get pulled out to do the render. is there something i am missing here

Comment: no i guess. try setting the url option in form_for. have you added resources new_hire_requests in routes.rb so that REST stuff can work ?

Comment: that's what was missing, i had new_hire_requests as a resource but with only: :create, i added :edit and it now works. thanks!

Comment: alright. i will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add resources new_hire_requests in the routes and get done with it .